# How to configure Pycharm to debug django

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am trying to set up Pycharm3.0 to be able to debug the django project.. I cannot get it to work. Any help is greatly appreciated..! ：-）

I checked the django support is there:
[image]

I then configured the Run/debug configuration settings as following:

[image]

.
sitee is the project folder.

When I hit the debug button, I got error:

> /usr/bin/python2.7 manage.py runserver
>   /home/tee/Downloads/pycharm-3.0.2/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc
>   --client 127.0.0.1 --port 40239 --file /home/tee/PycharmProjects/sitee/account/views.py Usage: manage.py
>   runserver [options] [optional port number, or ipaddr:port]
>
> Starts a lightweight Web server for development and also serves static
>   files.
>
> manage.py: error: no such option: --multiproc
>
> Process finished with exit code 2

Comment: What OS are you using? That looks way different from my PyCharm setup dialog.

Comment: The command should look more like this: `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /Applications/PyCharm.app/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --client 127.0.0.1 --port 58654 --file /Users/<username>/PycharmProjects/<project_name>/manage.py runserver 8000`

Comment: Leave `interpreter options` and `working directory` blank. You may need to add your `settings.py` to `environment variables`, but PyCharm usually sets all that stuff automatically.

Comment: @RobL I am using linux ubuntu.

Comment: So it looks to me like the `manage.py runserver 8000` command is being called first, rather than last. Perhaps you could try entering it in the PyCharm terminal? Not a fix, but it may give some clues.

Comment: Anyone still looking for answer to this should refer to the similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition

Answer (score 2):

I was doing the same thing with PyCharm 2019.I had no trouble. I set the script path to my manage.py file added runserver as the parameter and set the working directory to my source drive.

[image: Run/Debug Config]

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you are trying to debug using the 'Python' Run/Debug configuration rather than the 'Django server'.    Check your left hand column, the one that lists your Run/Debug configs and the defaults that PyCharm provides.  Do you see "Django server"?

If so, clone that one and use it.  You hardly need to specify any parameters, it does a lot with the defaults straight out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm in MacOS and I only needed to add the arguments for pointing to the different setting file's path.

[image]