# How to run Debug server for Django project in PyCharm Community Edition?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

Community Edition of the PyCharm is lacking the project type option on project setup and then when I set up Debug or Run configurations it asks me for a script it should run. What script would it be for Django, `manage.py`?

Comment: I notice that server breakpoints are masked when client breakpoints are present. Try removing all client breakpoints to see your server breakpoints get hit.

Comment: Judicious use of sleep() in the client code prevents the browser from breaking the connection while you're in the debugger on the server.

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Yes you can.

1. In Run -> Edit Configurations create new configuration
2. [+] / Python
3. Name: runserver
4. Scrip Path: path_to/manage.py
5. Parameters: runserver

Comment: Great thanks @Zlatko Rončević, I worked out the answer shortly after I posted the question but never updated it here - yours is exactly what worked for me. I am sorry I won't be able to vote it up as I have too small reputation :( But I would if I had it. Other people viewing this question please do so.

Comment: If you have environment variables, you should run PyCharm with the constants set from command line.

Comment: @niran for debug just start same configuration with Debug command (Run -> Debug)

Comment: @ZlatkoRončevi same thing I followed debugger is starting but when I open browser and debugger is not bringing cursor to the break points

Comment: if you want to runserver on specific port just add a space-separated port number after runserver parameters. example `runserver 8002`

Answer (score 3):

[image]

this is a configuration for run/debug django in pycharm.

Comment: This is not community version