# Debugging Django Project in PyCharm 4.0 Educational Edition

Tags: python, django, django-views, pycharm

I have a Django Project that I use through the PyCharm 4.0 Educational IDE.
Problem is that when I navigate to the localhost url where I am trying to debug ym view, the breakpoints don't take effects and I can't see the values of variables and functions at or before the breakpoint.

I've been googling and saw some old  configs from PyCharm 3.0 and some other posts mostly from 2011. I need the current version set up and also not to buy the PyCharm Pro edition.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

this could be a comment, but let me tell you what you need.

```
print variable
#... other stuff
print variable
```

this is the best debugging tool ever. use your own code to debug, this is the best experience i have seen so far.

Comment: I can't exactly just print on the website. Theres no place that would be assigned where I could see it. I want to use the native Django debugger

Comment: @KyleCalica-St you dont print on website. you see it in your console of course

Comment: Yeah I see it now, its very small compared to all the post and get request. Thanks, but it still doesnt answer my problems. I am just going to make another question with specifics cause my project is getting quite cumbersome. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: here is better answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition