# How to store Run/Debug Configuration in git repo

Tags: pycharm

I created a small Python project at github [who-and-what-is-xyz](https://github.com/guettli/who-or-what-is-xyz).

I would like to make it super easy for other developers who use PyCharm to start developing.

I would like to store some "Run/Debug Configuration" in the git repo.

For example: Starting the runserver. Like explained here: [How to run Debug server for Django project in PyCharm Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition)

After cloning the repo from github the config to run "runserver" should be available.

How can I store this in git?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to share Run/Debug configurations using an option present in the Configuration window called *Share through VCS*. 
In this way, your colleagues should be able to get and to use them without problems.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-run-debug-configurations.html) a useful tutorial from PyCharm site.