# How to use Django shell to interact with running server?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In the `apps.py` of one of my apps I set some class variables for models that can't be set at initialization because they depend on other apps and the models in them. This works fine and the class variables are set, but what I want to do is then test these classes to see if they'll work as intended. My problem is the class variables are set when I run the development server, but I want to also be able to create new instances of these models for testing. I realize that this can be accomplished by building the front-end that will interact with the models in production, but this seems to be excessive for simple testing.

Is there a way to use Django's shell on a currently running server, or do I have to go through importing and running all the things that `manage.py` usually takes care of on its own?

In case what I have written isn't clear, here's an example of the files in question:

```py
# example.models.py

from django.db.models import *

class ExampleModel(Model):
    class_var = None
    
    .
    .
    .
```

```py
# apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig


class ExampleConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'example'

    def ready(self):
        from example.models import ExampleModel
        ExampleModel.class_var = 'something'
```

Answer (score 1):

When you run `python manage.py shell` alot of the same set up happens as what happens when you run `runserver`. In particular, all of the `ready` methods in your `AppConfig`s will be called.

For this reason there is no need for your server to be running to do the testing you want.

You can even test this. Simply add a `print("This happens")` and run `python manage.py shell`. You should see something like this:

```
(env)your-current-location % python manage.py shell
This happens       <---- Here you see it is printed 
Python 3.8.6 (default, Oct  8 2020, 14:06:32)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>>
```

For what it's worth, you can open a shell, and run your server at the same time yes. But these will be different processes, and variables set on classes, will refer to differnt things. They will be (at the code level) completely separate.

Comment: Yes I did not want to be working on two instances of the website. Turns out the real bug  was something else the end, but wouldn't have noticed it without this, so thanks!

Comment: Is it possible to have an interactive session with runserver? I need to be able to test as I go along sometimes and being able to see and interact with created variables in the python console would be ideal.

Comment: Found an answer: Using the Pycharm debugger with a run configuration that brings up the server you should be able to interactively test django variables while clicking around on the site. Setting appropriate breakpoints is necessary in this case.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition/28256637#28256637

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer as the keywords I searched brought me here.

If the reader has pycharm or another IDE with debug configuration capability, then a way to interact with a django server that's currently running is to create a configuration file that runs the browser and placing breakpoints at variables you wish to test/interact with.

Within pycharm I went to:

1. Run in the top Menu
2. Edit Configuration (this should lead to the Run/Debug Configurations Menu)

- you can make your own or edit the django server run file

3. Check Run Browser

That was all, I left the Add Content Roots and Add Source Roots to pythonpath the same and it simply worked. I did add django_settings_module=mysite.settings to the environment variables but that may not be necessary. If you see errors regarding app or models not loaded then that may be a fix for you.

Reference: [How to run Debug server for Django project in PyCharm Community Edition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition/28256637#28256637)

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out!

What I was doing was trying to run the server (`python manage.py runserver`) in debug mode in PyCharm, then starting the interactive shell (`python manage.py shell`) in another terminal window, and then running a command from the **shell** while hoping that my breakpoint will get triggered. I can't test from runserver as I just have the backend for this project so far.

But from @tim-mccurrach's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65583727/8285811) above:

> For what it's worth, you can open a shell, and run your server at the same time yes. But these will be different processes, and variables set on classes, will refer to different things. They will be (at the code level) completely separate.

I understood that this was essentially like starting two servers... That's why the breakpoint was never getting triggered. And I confirmed this because the shell still works perfectly fine even if the server has not yet been started.

Instead, all I needed to do was to just **run the PyCharm debugger directly against the shell** (`python manage.py shell`) and then everything worked as expected! With the caveat that the debugger just exits after every error.