# How to debug a Django app with PYCHARM Community Edition

Tags: python, django, pycharm

i'm trying to debug a Django application on `Pycharm Community Edition 2020.3`, but can't because the breakpoints are **NOT** reaching or activating. I followed a YouTube tutorial and this [stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269574/how-to-run-debug-server-for-django-project-in-pycharm-community-edition) for configuring a debugging session on Django , both have the same steps.
I'll attach a screenshot of the configuration of my debugging session:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldfXJ.png) (sorry stack overflow doesn't allow me to show it directly)
Any ideas, comments or thoughts. I'm new to Python and Django so please have patient with me.
PS: this is my first time debugging an application on Pycharm, i did try debugging on Vscode and indeed **works**, but i rather use Pycharm

Answer (score 0):

**I SOLVED IT.**
Well, deleting the `.idea/` hidden folder, do the job for me. As i said it's **hidden**, so you have to enable make hidden folders visible on your OS, or open your project on Vs Code and delete it.